# Parse list object json using Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

i'm trying to parse Json with the google Gson library, but for the moment i can't get it to work ...

Here is the Json i'm supposed to get :

```
{
"shoppingLists": [
    {
        "ShoppingList": {
            "id": "51",
            "name": "loool",
            "created": "2014-03-22 13:03:22",
            "modified": "2014-03-22 13:03:22"
        },
        "ShoppingItem": [
            {
                "id": "24",
                "shopping_item_category_id": "19",
                "name": "Biscuits",
                "description": "",
                "created": "2014-02-05 17:43:45",
                "modified": "2014-02-05 17:43:45",
                "category_name": "Confiseries \/ Gouters"
            },
            {
                "id": "25",
                "shopping_item_category_id": "19",
                "name": "Snickers",
                "description": "",
                "created": "2014-02-05 17:44:08",
                "modified": "2014-02-05 17:44:08",
                "category_name": "Confiseries \/ Gouters"
            },
            {
                "id": "26",
                "shopping_item_category_id": "19",
                "name": "C\u00e9reales",
                "description": "",
                "created": "2014-02-05 17:44:57",
                "modified": "2014-02-05 17:44:57",
                "category_name": "Confiseries \/ Gouters"
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
}
```

Here are my models :

shoppingLists :

```
public class shoppingLists {
        public ShoppingList ShoppingList;
        public List<ShoppingItem> ShoppingItems;
}
```

ShoppingList :

```
public class ShoppingList {
public int id;
public String name;
public String created;
public String modified;
}
```

ShoppingItem :

```
public class ShoppingItem {
public int id;
public int shopping_item_category_id;
public String name;
public String description;
public String created;
public String modified;
public String category_name;
}
```

Here is my AsyncTask which get the Json from the server :

```
public class APIRetrieveLists extends AsyncTask<APIRequestModel, Void, List<shoppingLists>>{

SQLHelper _sqlHelper = null;
Context _context;
ProgressBar _pb;

public APIRetrieveLists(Context context, ProgressBar pb){
    this._context = context;
    this._pb = pb;
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<shoppingLists> model){
    this._sqlHelper = new SQLHelper(this._context);
    if (model != null){
        for (shoppingLists cn : model){
            Log.i("infos", "list's name => " + cn.ShoppingList.name);
        }
    }else{
        Log.i("infos", "model is null");
    }
}

@Override
protected List<shoppingLists> doInBackground(APIRequestModel... arg0) {
    APIRequestModel model = arg0[0];
    try
    {
        try
        {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token", model.getToken()));
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://apiurl/index.json");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String s = "";
            String all = "";
            while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null){
                all += s;
            }
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            List<shoppingLists> Obj = (List<shoppingLists>) gson.fromJson(all, new TypeToken<List<shoppingLists>>(){}.getType());
            return (Obj);
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.i("infos", "first");
            return (null);
        } 
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("infos", "second");
        return (null);
    }
}
}
```

The exception "second" is always firing ...
Log.i("infos", "model is null"); is also executed.
if someone could help :)
thank you !
regards.

[image: json]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add one more wrapper to your shoppingLists, as your jsonObject had shoppingLists as key and array of ShoppingListItem as value. Also you need to annotate `@SerializedName` for ShoppingItems field because it is not matching with the key in Json.

Find below updated classes and parser

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
FinalClass myObj = gson.fromJson(jsonString, FinalClass.class);
```

Classes

```
public class FinalClass {
    public ArrayList<ShoppingListItem> shoppingLists;
}

public class ShoppingListItem {
    public ShoppingList ShoppingList;
    @SerializedName("ShoppingItem")
    public List<ShoppingItem> ShoppingItems;
}

public class ShoppingList {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String created;
    public String modified;
}

public class ShoppingItem {
   public int id;
   public int shopping_item_category_id;
   public String name;
   public String description;
   public String created;
   public String modified;
   public String category_name;
}
```

Comment: Still getting the second exception, is the class name important to the parser ?

Comment: @bottus can you paste the exception/Logcat you are getting? class name can be anything.. but important thing is object/variable should match with keys in json

Comment: Here is the exception : com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 6

Comment: @bottus Can you paste your exact complete Json response you are receiving from web service? As per Json you provided in your question, I am suggesting the changes..

Comment: i can't get it in eclipse properly displayed ... any advice about this please ?

Comment: i added an image to show you, quicker for you and me, i belive that i miss a '{' at the begining ...

Comment: yeah, that was it ... thank you so much Uttam, you were a great help, thanks for this and thanks for your time ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a list of `shoppingLists` items in the json - if my glasses don't fool me. So changing: 
`List<shoppingLists> Obj = (List<shoppingLists>) gson.fromJson(all, new TypeToken<List<shoppingLists>>(){}.getType());`

into:

```
shoppingLists obj = gson.fromJson(all, shoppingLists.class);
```

will not cause any runtime gson exceptions. Eventually you can wrap that single parsed `obj` into a `List` so it matches with your current code. For Example:

```
shoppingLists obj = gson.fromJson(all, shoppingLists.class);
ArrayList<shoppingLists> result = new ArrayList<shoppingLists>();
result.add(obj);
return result;
```

Comment: i can eventually get several shoppingLists, i changed my fromJson into                 List<shoppingLists> Obj = (List<shoppingLists>) gson.fromJson(all, shoppingLists.class); but it still doesn't work .. also i get a warning because of the cast

Comment: The thing is `gson.fromJson` will parse a `shoppingLists`. Casting that to a list will throw a runtime exception. Updating the answer a bit.

Comment: Still getting an exception even with what you said gunar, and adding the obj to the list is okay but imagine that i have several shoppingLists in the json, this woudn't work anymore right ?

Comment: I posted my answer considering above given JSON example. If you have cases when you receive an array, then that's a different story

Comment: most of the time i will receive an array ;) would you mind giving an example considering an array please gunar ?

Comment: If the server changes the data type of the response, then you're in trouble because you don't know how to parse the response. The answer from Uttam looks promising.

Comment: i mean this is always an array, but sometimes there will be just one object in it ;)